# Reverse Permutation Index

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have written a function that calculates the permutations of an array [a,b,c,...] from an index, e.g.:

```
0 -> a b c 
1 -> a c b 
2 -> b a c
3 -> b c a
4 -> c a b
5 -> c b a
```

by this recursive function:

```
function factorial(n) { return n <= 1 ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1); }
function permutation(ar, n) {
   if (ar.length == 1) return [ar[0]]; 
   var x = factorial(ar.length-1);  // get first element
   return ar.splice(Math.floor(n/x),1).concat( permutation( ar, n % x ) )
}
```

Now I am looking for a function taking the index of a permutation to get the index of the reversed permutation, i.e.

```
    index    perm    reversed  reversed index
    **0** -> a b c -> c b a -> **5**
    **1** -> a c b -> b c a -> **3**
    **2** -> b a c -> c a b -> **4**
    **3** -> b c a -> a c b -> **1**
    **4** -> c a b -> b a c -> **2**
    **5** -> c b a -> a b c -> **0**
```

I can of calculate all permutation, calculate their reverse and build its index, but it seems there should be a mathematical way to get the index of the reverse permutation without calculating it.

Answer (score 3):

if you take a look at your permutations ,you'll find that it is structured as follows: (example for lenght = 3)

first your permutations are divided in 3 groups each containing 2! elements
those sub groups are then divided in 2 groups of lenght 1! , after which the sub-sub groups aren't divided anymore.

so in fact your permutation can be 'looked up' by first stating which sub-group it is in then stating which sub-sub group it is in ...

for example permutation 2:'bac' is in sub-group 1 (starting from 0) and in sub-sub group 0.

so we could say 2 = (1,0), as in 3 = 1*(2!)+0*(1!)
4 would then be (2,0)
now if we flip 2 so it's (0,1) and add 4,(2,0) to it we would get (2,1)
and this is true for all permutations

in essence:
(n = length of permutations)

write your index as a*(n-1)! + b*(n-2)! + ... + z*(1!)    ( a = floor(index / (n-1)),  b = floor ((index%(n-1))/(n-2)!) , ... )

find a number so that if you flip the smallest one and add them together you get (n-1,n-2,n-3,...,1)

there is probably an effecient algoritm which does this.

Comment: I do not get, what you mean by "flip the smallest one and add them together". Lets make an example - lets take the permutation [c,a,d,b] from the alphabet [a,b,c,d]. It has the index (2,0,1) or 2*6+0*2+1*1 = 13 ... What do I flip now?

Comment: I can transform that index back to a sequence like (2,0,3,1), reverse that (1,3,0,2), calculate the index from that (1,2,0) and get an index from that 1*6+2*2 = 10 ... Is there a way to directly get from (2,0,1) -> (1,2,0) ? I wonder if there Is a relationship here, that can be evaluated without actually reversing the index? Or if an index can be build that is easier to reverse?

Comment: i haven't looked into it to much it's just a relationship i found that i thought could be useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a mathematical way or not to achieve this but you can achieve this in a faster way by making use of a hashmap.

```
var dict = {};

dict['abc'] = 0;
dict['acb'] = 1;
dict['bac'] = 2;  
dict['bca'] = 3;
dict['cab'] = 4;
dict['cba'] = 5;
```

So once you have this, you can reverse a normal string and get the value of it's index using the above formed hashmap.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know I can build an index (hashmap) on the reversed items, but for this I would need to calculate them all (imagine the permutations array was not 3 but 300 elements long). I was interested if I could just by knowing the index of an entry calculate the index of the reverse entry (without even calculating the permutation itself).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit too late... It could be calculated. You can use this C# code as is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfPermutations
{
    public class PermutationOuelletLexico3<T>
    {
        // ************************************************************************
        private T[] _sortedValues;

        private bool[] _valueUsed;

        public readonly long MaxIndex; // long to support 20! or less 

        // ************************************************************************
        public PermutationOuelletLexico3(T[] sortedValues)
        {
            if (sortedValues.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sortedValues.Lenght should be greater than 0");
            }

            _sortedValues = sortedValues;
            Result = new T[_sortedValues.Length];
            _valueUsed = new bool[_sortedValues.Length];

            MaxIndex = Factorial.GetFactorial(_sortedValues.Length);
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        public T[] Result { get; private set; }

        // ************************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Return the permutation relative to the index received, according to 
        /// _sortedValues.
        /// Sort Index is 0 based and should be less than MaxIndex. Otherwise you get an exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sortIndex"></param>
        /// <param name="result">Value is not used as inpu, only as output. Re-use buffer in order to save memory</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void GetValuesForIndex(long sortIndex)
        {
            int size = _sortedValues.Length;

            if (sortIndex < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sortIndex should greater or equal to 0.");
            }

            if (sortIndex >= MaxIndex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sortIndex should less than factorial(the lenght of items)");
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < _valueUsed.Length; n++)
            {
                _valueUsed[n] = false;
            }

            long factorielLower = MaxIndex;

            for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            {
                long factorielBigger = factorielLower;
                factorielLower = Factorial.GetFactorial(size - index - 1);  //  factorielBigger / inverseIndex;

                int resultItemIndex = (int)(sortIndex % factorielBigger / factorielLower);

                int correctedResultItemIndex = 0;
                for(;;)
                {
                    if (! _valueUsed[correctedResultItemIndex])
                    {
                        resultItemIndex--;
                        if (resultItemIndex < 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    correctedResultItemIndex++;
                }

                Result[index] = _sortedValues[correctedResultItemIndex];
                _valueUsed[correctedResultItemIndex] = true;
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Calc the index, relative to _sortedValues, of the permutation received
        /// as argument. Returned index is 0 based.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="values"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public long GetIndexOfValues(T[] values)
        {
            int size = _sortedValues.Length;
            long valuesIndex = 0;

            List<T> valuesLeft = new List<T>(_sortedValues);

            for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            {
                long indexFactorial = Factorial.GetFactorial(size - 1 - index);

                T value = values[index];
                int indexCorrected = valuesLeft.IndexOf(value);
                valuesIndex = valuesIndex + (indexCorrected * indexFactorial);
                valuesLeft.Remove(value);
            }
            return valuesIndex;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I was looking for an answer if the reverse index can actually be built from the values index without needing to calculate the actual permutation. But thanks for the code - I guess it is pretty similar to the javascript code I posted above (although I am missing the reverse function above). Still: The point was to directly reverse the index without even needing to calculate the permutation. So I was looking more for a "mathematical" solution.

Comment: @MathiasMamsch, sorry for the delay, I'm in vacation. You have to look for function: >> public long GetIndexOfValues(T[] values) <<. It is not a direct math function. It is more an algo that it find its result where the complexity is function of the amount of items. (It is probably more than O(n) ,probably near O(n square)). But it is far faster than iterating over each possibilities until you reach the permutation :-).

Comment: @MathiasMamsch, I wrote a little article about it: Permutations: Fast implementations and a new indexing algorithm allowing multithreading:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1250925/Permutations-Fast-implementations-and-a-new-indexi